# Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined error JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

this is my javascript code but whenever I try to run it, it throws 'Error:  TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined' Can anyone please tell me why this is happening and also give me a solution how to fix it?

```js
app.post('/getElements', (req, res) => {
    fs.readFile('items.json', function(error, data) {
        if (error) {
            res.status(500).end()
        } else {
            try {
                const accountId = req.body.accountId //the value of it is 'data'
                const items = JSON.parse(data)

                items.accountId.forEach(function(item) {
                    const price = item.price

                    res.json({
                        price: price
                    })
                })
            } catch (err) {
                console.log('Error: ', err)
            }
        }
    })
})
```

Comment: So it is saying `accountId` is undefined. Meaning `console.log(items.accountId === undefined);` So you are not referencing the element correclty

Comment: What does items.json look like?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to check if the data that comes in has the format you need, then only run your `forEach` if `accountId` is type of array. If not, return something like `price not available`